# Strange Height Matching Behavior in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

I have a design which uses side-by-side divs that need to be height matched. This works perfectly well on page load, but on window resize, things tend to get all out of whack. The elements that are getting their heights changed are becoming larger or smaller than the heights of their target elements - sometimes by very large margins.

```
var specials = $('#specials');
var specialsPicture = $('#specials_contain .picture');
```

This is a function that gets called on page load and on the window resize event:

```
function matchAll() {
    match(specialsPicture, specials, {min: 768, max: null});
}
```

Here's the actual matching function:

```
function match(elem, target, range) {
    // if no max
    if (range.max == null) {

        // if in range
        if (window.innerWidth >= range.min) {

            // resize element to target height
            elem.outerHeight( target.outerHeight() );

        }

    // if there is a max
    } else {

        // if in range
        if (window.innerWidth >= range.min && window.innerWidth <= range.max) {

            // resize
            elem.outerHeight( target.outerHeight() );

        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image: issue]

It seems like such a simple piece of code, but I can't seem to figure out what might be happening. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if match(specialsPicture, specials, {min: 768, max: null}); called on load and on resize, the else part of the if statement would never execute since max is always null

Comment: It's not supposed to call the else. The issue is it's getting the wrong value for the height, and I don't know why. Inspecting the other element shows a different height than the one being resized

Comment: in the image it looks like the left side is at its min-height due to the amount of content in there. If you put overflow:hidden on the left side, you will probably see the height you have set. You should be able to see the height you set in the debugger as well

Comment: Tried setting it to overflow hidden, but still doing the same thing. There's no defined height on the left element. It almost seems like the same kind of issues you get when you try to access an elements dimensions before the window load event when they don't have a defined height. Not sure though.

Comment: can recreate this issue in a http://jsfiddle.net or give a link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R72ZV/5/. It works pretty well. It was hard for me to get it to break, but I did: http://i41.tinypic.com/xp672d.jpg